# Pure Javascript: onClick toggle rows/ image: Firefox/Chrome - works: IE - does not work

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

Got some great help from Zeb Rawnsley (you rock!) on resolving the preceding question to my current issue.

Working with some code to allow subordinate rows to be hidden via a collapsible link behind an image.  This works perfectly fine in Firefox and Chrome but the image does not alternate after the first iteration in IE (IE 8 specifically my company's standard).

The section of interest is here (I think):

`var closedImgHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"50\">";`

`var openImgHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"50\">";`

and possibly here (but I don't think so):

```
lnk.innerHTML =(lnk.innerHTML == openImgHTML)?closedImgHTML:openImgHTML;
```

This CodePen is for the working version (Firefox/Chrome):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjLvh

This is the HTML for the working version:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table { empty-cells: show; }
cell {font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11.0pt;color: #000000;}
TD{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt;}
TH{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> 
var tbl;
var toggleimage=new Array("http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png","http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png")

  var closedImgHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"50\">";

  var openImgHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"50\">";

function trim(str){
 return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");
}

function getParent(el, pTagName) {
 if (el == null) return null;
 else if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == pTagName.toLowerCase()) // Gecko bug, supposed to be uppercase
  return el;
 else
  return getParent(el.parentNode, pTagName);
}

function toggleSection(lnk){

 var td = lnk.parentNode;
 var table = getParent(td,'TABLE');
 var len = table.rows.length;
 var tr = getParent(td, 'tr');
 var rowIndex = tr.rowIndex;
 var rowHead=table.rows[rowIndex].cells[1].innerHTML;



lnk.innerHTML =(lnk.innerHTML == openImgHTML)?closedImgHTML:openImgHTML;

 vStyle =(tbl.rows[rowIndex+1].style.display=='none')?'':'none';

 for(var i = rowIndex+1; i < len;i++){
  if (table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML==rowHead){
    table.rows[i].style.display= vStyle;
    table.rows[i].cells[1].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
 }
}

function toggleRows(){
    tables =document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for(i =0; i<tables.length;i++){
      if(tables[i].className.indexOf("expandable") != -1)
        tbl =tables[i];
    }
    if(typeof tbl=='undefined'){
     alert("Could not find a table of expandable class");
     return;
    }

//assume the first row is headings and the first column is empty
 var len = tbl.rows.length;
var link ='<a href="#" onclick="toggleSection(this);return false;" style="text-decoration: none">'+closedImgHTML+'</a>';

 var rowHead = tbl.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;

 for (j=1; j<len;j++){
  //check the value in each row of column 2
  var m = tbl.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML;

if(m!=rowHead || j==1){
   rowHead=m;
   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = link;
//   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].style.textAlign="center";
   tbl.rows[j].style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  }
else
   tbl.rows[j].style.display = "none";
}

}
var oldEvt = window.onload;

var preload_image_1=new Image()
var preload_image_2=new Image()
preload_image_1.src=toggleimage[0]
preload_image_2.src=toggleimage[1]
var i_image=0

function testloading() {
    isloaded=true
}

function toggle() {
    if (isloaded) {
        document.togglepicture.src=toggleimage[i_image]
    }
    i_image++
    if (i_image>1) {i_image=0}
}

window.onload = function() { if (oldEvt) oldEvt(); toggleRows(); testloading();}


</SCRIPT>

<TABLE class=expandable width="400px" border="1"  cellspacing="0" frame="box" rules="all" >
  <THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TH  bgColor="#E6E4D4">&nbsp;</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Manager</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Sales Rep</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Amount </TH></TR>
</THEAD>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD><i>Georgia District Reps</i></TD>
    <TD>500000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Rex Smtih</TD>
    <TD>350000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Alex Anderson</TD>
    <TD>150000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD><i>Texas District Reps</i></TD>
    <TD>630000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD>Bill Smith</TD>
    <TD>410000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Hobby</TD>
    <TD>Simon Wilkes</TD>
    <TD>220000</TD></TR>
</TBODY></font></TABLE>
<br>
<br>
<a href="javascript:toggle()"></a>


</body>
</html>
```

The prior set of code without the images (using text for open/close) worked fine in all browsers.

Not sure if there is an image syntax issue in IE or something else.  It most certainly is focused on the images since, well, it works fine without images.

Here is the CodePen for the version (text based) working in IE (and others).

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/morpF

Here is the HTML for the "ALL" browser version"

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
table { empty-cells: show; }
cell {font-family:'Calibri';font-size:11.0pt;color: #000000;}
TD{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt;}
TH{font-family: Calibri; font-size: 10.5pt; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript> 
var tbl;

function trim(str){
 return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,"");
}

function getParent(el, pTagName) {
 if (el == null) return null;
 else if (el.nodeType == 1 && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == pTagName.toLowerCase()) // Gecko bug, supposed to be uppercase
  return el;
 else
  return getParent(el.parentNode, pTagName);
}

function toggleSection(lnk){

 var td = lnk.parentNode;
 var table = getParent(td,'TABLE');
 var len = table.rows.length;
 var tr = getParent(td, 'tr');
 var rowIndex = tr.rowIndex;
 var rowHead=table.rows[rowIndex].cells[1].innerHTML;

 lnk.innerHTML =(lnk.innerHTML == "+")?"--":"+";

 vStyle =(tbl.rows[rowIndex+1].style.display=='none')?'':'none';

 for(var i = rowIndex+1; i < len;i++){
  if (table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML==rowHead){
    table.rows[i].style.display= vStyle;
    table.rows[i].cells[1].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
 }
}

function toggleRows(){
    tables =document.getElementsByTagName("table");
    for(i =0; i<tables.length;i++){
      if(tables[i].className.indexOf("expandable") != -1)
        tbl =tables[i];
    }
    if(typeof tbl=='undefined'){
     alert("Could not find a table of expandable class");
     return;
    }

//assume the first row is headings and the first column is empty
 var len = tbl.rows.length;
 var link ='<a href="#" onclick="toggleSection(this);return false;" style="text-decoration: none">+</a>';

 var rowHead = tbl.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;

 for (j=1; j<len;j++){
  //check the value in each row of column 2
  var m = tbl.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML;

if(m!=rowHead || j==1){
   rowHead=m;
   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].innerHTML = link;
//   tbl.rows[j].cells[0].style.textAlign="center";
   tbl.rows[j].style.background = "#FFFFFF";
  }
else
   tbl.rows[j].style.display = "none";
}

}
var oldEvt = window.onload;
window.onload = function() { if (oldEvt) oldEvt(); toggleRows();}
</SCRIPT>

<TABLE class=expandable width="400px" border="1"  cellspacing="0" frame="box" rules="all" >
  <THEAD>
  <TR>
    <TH width="10%"  bgColor="#E6E4D4">&nbsp;</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Manager</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Sales Rep</TH>
    <TH bgColor="#E6E4D4" align="left">Amount </TH></TR></THEAD>
  <TBODY>
  <TR class="cell">
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp</TD>
    <TD>500000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Rex Smtih</TD>
    <TD>350000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>Sarah Jones</TD>
    <TD>Alex Anderson</TD>
    <TD>150000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Jones</TD>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>620000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Jones</TD>
    <TD>Bill Smith</TD>
    <TD>410000</TD></TR>
  <TR>
    <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
    <TD>William Jones</TD>
    <TD>Simon Wilkes</TD>
    <TD>220000</TD></TR>
</TBODY></font></TABLE></body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different browsers serialize the DOM differently.  Running your code in IE10 gives me this:

```
foo.innerHTML = "<img name=\"togglepicture\" src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png\" border=\"0\" height=\"50\">";

foo.innerHTML; // <img name="togglepicture" height="50" src="http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png" border="0">
```

IE rearranged the attributes, so you no longer have the same string.

Instead of getting the HTML inside the link element, get the image itself and look at its `src` property.

Comment: Dennis,  I understand what you are saying but I really am not sure what the next steps would be.  Can you give any additional direction?

Comment: Even if I remove any offending tags which could be "re-positioned"  the toggle still does not work in IE.        `var closedImgHTML = "<img src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_closed_folder.png\">";`
<br/>
`var openImgHTML = "<img src=\"http://www.iconlooker.com/user-content/uploads/wall/thumb/misc._icons_open_folder.png\">";`

Comment: Sorry this is really messy.  I cannot figure out how to add linebreak.  The instructions say <br/> but that does not work.

Comment: Back to my input about removing attributes.  I need the "border = 0" attribute or else IE will show that blasted blue border.  Searching in vain here.

Comment: Thinking out loud here.   

Instead of checking the value of innerhtml I should assume it starts as closed and if clicked change to open. Then when clicked again evaluate image source and return the opposite.  I would need to use an “if” statement rather than a ternary evaluation.

I guess more plainly simply evaluate source and return opposite.  The page will always load with a closed image.

Comment: [Does this make sense](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tDnHg)?  Also, you can't put line breaks in comments.  It's restricted to a subset of normal post markdown.

Comment: Yes, very much so Dennis. The revised portion `var img = lnk.children[0];
img.src =(img.src == toggleimage[0])?toggleimage[1]:toggleimage[0];` completely bypasses the evaluation based on InnerHTML.  I will need to keep this in my toolkit going forward.  Much appreciated!